# How to show some smooth coordinates do not exist for a simple metric

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I have a simple metric:

$$
ds^2=dr^2+r^2(1+kr)d\theta^2
$$

Near the origin $r=0$, I wanted to switch to (smooth) coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, but it seems this is only possible when $k$ is non-positive.  Assuming my conjecture is correct, what is the easiest way to confirm this and show the breakdown with $k$ positive?  We are used to spherical/polar coordinates not behaving at the origin, but for $k$ positive with this metric, it is the Cartesian coordinates that do not behave.  Also, if smoothness vs. mere continuity is important please explain.  Also, if you can tie it to Lie brackets, geodesics, affine parameters, etc. that would be nice.  (This question emerged from pondering Wald's *General Relativity* Chapter 11 Problem 3b.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That problem says in the edition I found "Show that  every $t=$ constant hypersurface in the Schwarzschild solution is an asymptotically flat initial data set." What has your metric to do with this? Why $k$ needs to be non-positive "near" the origin I simply don't get.

Comment: Hello Kurt, I'd rather the mathematicians address the question as posed before scaring them away with the physics.  I probably shouldn't have mentioned the Wald.  But since you were nice enough to respond, I'll tell you.  I think I can answer the Wald question with $R^2(1-2MR)$ as my conformal factor, but not with $R^2$.  It seems the latter should work, but not for me.  A lot turns on Wald's particular formulation of a direction directed limit which uses Cartesianish coordinates and now I'm betting all my money on it being impossible to set up his coordinates for $R^2$.

Comment: Ran out of space.  Take Schwarzchild and switch to $R=1/r$.  And I meant to say "direction dependent limit".

Comment: I do not understand the question. The curvature has a singularity at the origin: $$K=-\frac{k(1+\frac34kr)}{r(1+kr)^2}.$$ I do not see why the sign of $k$ is relevant.

Comment: Hello Ted.  Thanks. Is $K$ the same as the trace of the Ricci tensor?  And, you wrote "r" rather than "R".  Which did you intend?  I just tried to calculate the curvature and got something singular also, but I need to check my calculations in the morning.  It probably matters, but I'm not sure if it does for my purposes.  Here's the intuition.  Going $2\pi$ around a hill, the $d\theta$ part is less than going $2\pi$ times the distance up the hill to the top, the $dr$ part.  That seems to require k negative.   As k approaches zero, we get the plane.  But what is positive k?  Tomorrow, much more

Comment: I just mean the Gaussian curvature of the surface with local coordinates $(r,\theta)$ as you gave. (For a surface, the curvature tensor has up to sign none nonzero component.)  I'm not dealing with a higher-dimensional curvature tensor because I have only two coordinates. I wrote $r$ because you have coordinate $r$. I don't know where you got $R$. At any rate, I concede that there cannot be local coordinates with (smooth, nondegenerate) metric, since the curvature has a singularity; but I continue not to understand how the sign on the constant $k$ can make a difference. Oh, $R=1/r$ ...

Comment: I see. So you're really trying to work at $\infty$, but then we have to rewrite the metric in $R,\theta$ coordinates. You can't just substitute at the end.

Comment: Hello Ted.  Yes, I was mistaken.  There is a singularity irrespective of the sign of k.  So I suppose that is a sufficient condition to not be able to cover that point with a smooth chart.  A more interesting example is $ds^2=dr^2+\sin^2(r)d\theta^2$  This is sphere with constant curvature.  I can switch to Cartesianish coordinates and it behaves well in the limit, but I guess I would have to verifiy all deriviatives exist by hand to actually prove the chart is smooth.  You keep getting $sin(\alpha)/\alpha$ type expressions.  That's looking at the metric not directly the chart.  Monday more.ty

Comment: I do not yet have a general answer to the question posed, but have moved on to the physics question from Wald here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783729/asymptotically-flat-initial-data-sets-for-schwarzschild